# what's the best way in VIM to get output like 'occur' does in Emacs

Tags: search, vim

I'd like to search some string(regex) in bunch of files in VIM. I'd like to have the output looks like the 'occur' does in Emacs. i.e. a seperated buffer open, list the lines which match the search, and will open the file if move the cursor to the line and push Return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `:grep pattern *.ext` but there are different ways. Fully explained http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim

Answer (score 2):

I've written a couple of plug-ins that wrap :vimgrep and the like, to make the results easier to navigate, show context, etc.

For searching across open/listed buffers, there is [Buffersaurus](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3620).

For searching across the filesystem, there is [Filesearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3646).

Answer (score 1):

There is a occur like plugin for Vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2262

Comment: Looks good. However, looks like there is a bug in current version. when you jump to the occur point by pressing button in the occur buffer, the file buffer will lose syntax highlight. Thanks for the information!

Comment: You're welcome. The plugin is rather outdated also. I would use something like Buffersaurus from Jeet's answer, Unite etc instead.